# Синтаксический разбор предложения - устойчивого выражения

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Предложение такое: ***С лёгким паром!***

Вопрос: можно ли разобрать его по членам?

Это неделимый оборот, устойчивая фраза. Роль в предложении мне неясна. Сказуемое? Или просто какое-то восклицание в роли междометия, без определённой синтаксической функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"С лёгким паром!" - этикетная формула, близкая к междометию.

Этикетные междометия способны образовывать так называемые междометные нечленимые предложения. Они не разбираются по членам предложения, ничего не называют и выполняют лишь коммуникативную функцию.Хотя сохранение связи с омонимичными знаменательными словами, а также потенциальная (этимологическая) способность этих слов иметь зависимые слова позволяет таким предложениям иметь второстепенные члены. Например:

– Всем добрый день, – сухо поприветствовал Грин, не глядя на собравшихся. (Б.Акунин);

Счастливо вам, ребята, – сказал он слесарям (И.Герасимов);

Счастливо и вам, товарищи!Дай Бог вам всего доброго! Спасибо вам, родные наши! (А.Твардовский)

Предложения, образованные этими междометиями, занимают промежуточное положение между «односоставными и нечленимыми предложениями».

Преимущественно они построены по схемам односоставных предложений с разной степенью логико-семантической и синтаксической членимости, в них «прямые синтаксические связи или отсутствуют, или затемнены».(П.А. Лекант)

У нас построено по схеме эллипсиса.

Я думаю, возможно сказать так: ***междометная этикетная формула в виде нечленимого предложения, построенного по схеме эллипсиса, выполняет коммуникативную функцию.***

Вот здесь методика объяснения материала на уровне учителя:

http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200601506

Comment: Благодарю Вас. На уроке РЯ в 7 классе возник этот вопрос, пообещала детям разобраться.